# Nhibernate Multidatabase Connection

Tags: c#, .net, database, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4

We appreciate any hep with the following problem.

We are developping an application using MVC4 and NHibernate.

The application must handle multidatabase connections.

Each client has his own database, so there is an initial login form that connects to a database clients, once the credentials are checked we must stablish the connection to the especific client database.

We have been working on this problem for severals days and this is the solution on wich we are working till now:

We have created a property on the global.asax with a SessionFactory Dictionary.
Every time a client login we add a new SessionFactory to the Dictionary.

We have created an ActionFilter to control on every action the bind and the unbind of the nhibernate session, as follows:

```
  public class SessionPerRequest : ActionFilterAttribute   {

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Boreas.Subsistemas.Cliente.VO.Nuestro_ClienteVO cliente = (Boreas.Subsistemas.Cliente.VO.Nuestro_ClienteVO)filterContext.HttpContext.Session["Cliente"];

        NHibernate.ISession session = MvcApplication.getSession(cliente).OpenSession();

        session.BeginTransaction();

        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        Boreas.Subsistemas.Cliente.VO.Nuestro_ClienteVO cliente = (Boreas.Subsistemas.Cliente.VO.Nuestro_ClienteVO)filterContext.HttpContext.Session["Cliente"];

        NHibernate.ISession session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(MvcApplication.getSession(cliente));

        if (session != null)
        {
            if (session.Transaction.IsActive)
            {
                try
                {
                    session.Transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch
                {
                    session.Transaction.Rollback();
                }
            }

            session.Close();
        }

        MvcApplication.removeSession(cliente);
    }
}
```

And those are the methods on the global.asax that create, delete and return the session factory to each client:

```
public static void addSession(Boreas.Subsistemas.Cliente.VO.Nuestro_ClienteVO cliente)
    {
        if (!DictionarySessionFactory.ContainsKey(cliente))
        {
            ISessionFactory Session;
            var nhibernateConiguration = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
            nhibernateConiguration.SetProperty("connection.connection_string",    cliente.baseDatosClienteBoreas);

            nhibernateConiguration.Configure();
            SessionFactory = nhibernateConiguration.BuildSessionFactory();           
        }          
    }

    public static void removeSession(Boreas.Subsistemas.Cliente.VO.Nuestro_ClienteVO cliente)
    {
        if (cliente != null)
        {
            if (DictionarySessionFactory.ContainsKey(cliente))
            {
                DictionarySessionFactory.Remove(cliente);
            }
        }
    }

    public static ISessionFactory getSession(Boreas.Subsistemas.Cliente.VO.Nuestro_ClienteVO cliente)
    {
        ISessionFactory Session;

        if (cliente == null)
        {               
            var nhibernateConiguration = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
            nhibernateConiguration.SetProperty("connection.connection_string", "Data Source=BENITO-PC\\WINCODICE;Initial Catalog=ClientesBoreasRutas;User ID=sa;Password=2144;");

            nhibernateConiguration.Configure();
            Session = nhibernateConiguration.BuildSessionFactory();
            //DictionarySessionFactory.Add(null, Session);
            return Session;
        }
        else {
            if (DictionarySessionFactory.ContainsKey(cliente))
            {
                return DictionarySessionFactory[cliente];
            }
            else
            {
                var nhibernateConiguration = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
                nhibernateConiguration.SetProperty("connection.connection_string", cliente.baseDatosClienteBoreas);
                nhibernateConiguration.Configure();
                Session = nhibernateConiguration.BuildSessionFactory();
                DictionarySessionFactory.Add(cliente, Session);
                return SessionFactory;               
            }

        }               

    }
```

The problem is that the application returns a **Nhibernate.HibernateException "No session bound to the current context"**

We would appreciate any help to solve the problem, and also would be interesting to listen to any other proper way to implement multi database connections with Nhibernate and mvc4.

Thank u very much for reading my post

Answer (score 0):

In your OnResultExecuted method doesn't this line:

```
NHibernate.ISession session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(MvcApplication.getSession(cliente));
```

unbinds the transaction from the current context before it is being commited? This line should come once you are done with the session.

Before you commit the transaction you should retrieve the session (by calling GetCurrentSession() on the the SessionFactory) commit the transaction on it and then unbind it.